# How to download old versions android sdk platforms with android studio 2.3.2?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

In Tools > Android > SDK Manager > SDK Platform, I cannot see any other older version except Android 7.1.1 . Is is casued by my newtork issues?

[image]

Comment: it suppose to show other platform plus link to sdk manager too

Comment: what happens if you click "show package details"?

Answer (score 0):

Check SDK tools there will be checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky (maybe unlucky), this issue is mostly caused by firewall settings. Check "SDK Update Sites, and you might see red markings in the first column like this":

[image]